# Write the Brute Force Recursive Code to generate the longest substring containing k distinct vowels

Tags: algorithms, recursion

Given a string s we have to find the length of the longest substring of s which contain exactly K distinct vowels.
This is the problem statment given on geeksforgeeks
Input : s = “artyebui”, k = 2
Output : 6
The only solution present on geeksforgeeks is the dynamic programming one. Can someone help with the recursive solution?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? It is expected of you to show your partial progress, thoughts or where you got stuck. This site is a knowledge-sharing question-and-answer place instead of a solution rendering service.

Comment: Hi.. I am new to this place. Will definitely take care next time. Can you please help me with the question?

Comment: Please edit your post to add a reference to the article on GeeksforGeeks.

Comment: The brute force solution just tries all substrings. I'm not sure what a recursive solution would look like.